# How to change y axis label in primeng barchart?

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to display a barchart with number of days (2,4,6,8,10..)on y-axis and org1,org2,org3 on x-axis. By default number of days are displayed as 10,20,30 on y-axis. can you please let me know how to change that.

** component.ts **

```
 this.chartdata = {
            labels: ['Org1', 'Org2', 'Org3', 'Org4', 'Org5', 'Org6', 'Org7'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: '< 7 days',
                     backgroundColor: '#9CCC65',
                    borderColor: '#7CB342',
                    data: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]
                },
                {
                    label: '< 14 days',
                    backgroundColor: '#f4eb3d',
                    borderColor: '#f4eb3d',
                    data: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21]
                },
                 {
                    label: '> 21 days',
                    backgroundColor: '#ef220b',
                    borderColor: '#ef220b',
                    data: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9,12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]
                }

            ]
        }
```

** HTML Page **

```
<p-chart type="bar" [data]="chartdata"></p-chart>
```

** Output **

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify chart options as

```
<p-chart type="bar" [data]="chartdata" [options]="chartOptions"></p-chart>
```

and then you can change the y-axis ticks in the options:

```
public chartOptions = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 2,
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  }
}
```